# Difficulty changing the size of image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

**Problem**:
I use the following code inside the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set the size of the image for the cell, yet at runtime the image gets blown up to the maximum height and width that the table row will allow.

```
UIImage *_image = [imageDictionary objectForKey:@"image"]; // Get image data
[_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)]; // set size
[cell.imageView setImage: _image]; // assign image to cell
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.imageView.frame.origin.x,cell.imageView.frame.origin.y,50,50);

return cell;
```

**Question**: Is there a more robust method of controlling the size of the image in a UITableViewCell? The approach I'm taking comes from several other posts but for some reason its being ignored in my code.

**Side-note:** I'm using Xcode 5 and developing on an iOS 7 platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UITableViewCell **contentView** .

The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so **they will be positioned appropriately** as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

**Example:**

```
 UIImage *_image = [imageDictionary objectForKey:@"image"]; // Get image data
 [_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)]; // set size

 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: _image];
 [imageView setFrame:yourFrame];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question but your underlying problem is your approach. You should be customizing your cells by subclassing UITableViewCell. To add to that it's a lot easier to manipulate cell contents as views than to play around with the default picture and text label they give you. To carify, the contents of the cell sit on a view known as contentView accessible as cell.contentView. You can add text labels, buttons, and images as subviews to any location with any size you want the same way you would do with any view added as a subview.